# Raspberry Pi Stretch visual studio code Python ImportError cannot import name

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm running Raspbian Stretch, everything is up to date.  I'm using visual studio code and writing Python.  I'm try to run a simple piece of code in a tutorial:

```
from datetime import date
print(date.today())
```

I get an error message saying:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Python/datetime.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Python/datetime.py", line 1, in <module>
    from datetime import date
  File "/home/pi/Python/datetime.py", line 1, in <module>
    from datetime import date
ImportError: cannot import name 'date'
```

The interpreter is using Python 3.5.3 32-bit.  If I switch the interpreter to Python 2.7, it works.  If I run those two lines of code in a terminal using python or python 3, both work.  It is just this one interpreter in VS code.  I uninstalled and reinstalled python 3.5.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is `datetime` installed on the Pi? Is your file called `datetime` causing a name collision?

Comment: Yes, it's installed.  It works in vs code with 2.7 selected.  It works in the terminal with both 2.7 and 3.5.  I also tried adding it via the terminal in vs code.  Of those 4 scenarios it's only the one that isn't working.

Comment: You were right... having the file named datetime.py caused a collision.  2 hours and a desperate cry to stackover... thank you.